# How to perform str_replace on the results of wp_list_pages

Tags: theme-development, wp-list-pages

I am trying to target and replace the text produced by a function. I'm not too sure what I'm doing wrong.

```
$InnerPages = wp_list_pages('child_of='.($post->post_parent != false ? $post->post_parent : $post->ID).'&title_li=&echo=0');
echo $InnerPages;
```

Outputs:

```
<ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2
        <ul class="children">
            <li>2.1</li>
        </ul>
   </li>
</ul>
```

I want to modify the `<ul class="children">` so I try to perform a str_replace:

```
$InnerPages = wp_list_pages('child_of='.($post->post_parent != false ? $post->post_parent : $post->ID).'&title_li=&echo=0')
$InnerPages = str_replace('<ul class="children">',
                          '<ul class="children"><li>Overview</li>',
                          $InnerPages);
echo $InnerPages;
```

But this does nothing, I'm new to PHP so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

**EDIT**

I changed the code to reflect the changes I've made so far after some troubleshooting (see below). The code still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Change your `$child` in your code to `$InnerPages`, like this:

```
$InnerPages = wp_list_pages('child_of='.($post->post_parent != false ? $post->post_parent : $post->ID).'&title_li=&echo=0');
$InnerPages = str_replace('<ul class="children">',
                               '<ul class="children"><li>Overview</li>',
                               $InnerPages);
echo $InnerPages;
```

You were saving your change in $child but then displaying $InnerPages which was unchanged.  Additionally the class is `children` and not `child` and must match exactly to work.

Edit to accommodate comments:

If I take your output:

```
<li class="page_item page-item-113 page_item_has_children current_page_item"><a href="http://127.0.0.1/abbatech/procurement-capabilities/los-alamos-national-laboratory/">Los Alamos National Laboratory</a>
<ul class="children">
    <li class="page_item page-item-115"><a href="http://127.0.0.1/abbatech/procurement-capabilities/los-alamos-national-laboratory/online-contact-form/">Online Contact Form</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li class="page_item page-item-95"><a href="http://127.0.0.1/abbatech/procurement-capabilities/nasa-sewp-v/">NASA SEWP V</a></li>
<li class="page_item page-item-2"><a href="http://127.0.0.1/abbatech/procurement-capabilities/sample-page/">Sample Page</a></li>
```

And I apply your code, corrected according to my answer:

```
$InnerPages = '
<li class="page_item page-item-113 page_item_has_children current_page_item"><a href="http://127.0.0.1/abbatech/procurement-capabilities/los-alamos-national-laboratory/">Los Alamos National Laboratory</a>
<ul class="children">
<li class="page_item page-item-115"><a href="http://127.0.0.1/abbatech/procurement-capabilities/los-alamos-national-laboratory/online-contact-form/">Online Contact Form</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li class="page_item page-item-95"><a href="http://127.0.0.1/abbatech/procurement-capabilities/nasa-sewp-v/">NASA SEWP V</a></li>
<li class="page_item page-item-2"><a href="http://127.0.0.1/abbatech/procurement-capabilities/sample-page/">Sample Page</a></li>
';

$InnerPages = str_replace('<ul class="children">',
    '<ul class="children"><li>Overview</li>',
    $InnerPages);
echo $InnerPages;
```

I get this output:

```
<li class="page_item page-item-113 page_item_has_children current_page_item"><a href="http://127.0.0.1/abbatech/procurement-capabilities/los-alamos-national-laboratory/">Los Alamos National Laboratory</a>
<ul class="children"><li>Overview</li>
    <li class="page_item page-item-115"><a href="http://127.0.0.1/abbatech/procurement-capabilities/los-alamos-national-laboratory/online-contact-form/">Online Contact Form</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li class="page_item page-item-95"><a href="http://127.0.0.1/abbatech/procurement-capabilities/nasa-sewp-v/">NASA SEWP V</a></li>
<li class="page_item page-item-2"><a href="http://127.0.0.1/abbatech/procurement-capabilities/sample-page/">Sample Page</a></li>
```

So, what isn't working?

Comment: I had also tried that because the piece of code I originally found did that, but it does nothing. I just retested it using your code (I added a ; to the end of the first $InnerPages) and it produced no changes to the output.

Comment: Did you paste your output or type it?

Comment: Do you mean in the post? I typed.

Comment: Can we see the actual output pasted in instead?

Comment: Sure. I also made a mistake in the post, it's "children" instead of "child" in the ul. I made sure to make the change in the php. http://pastebin.com/9PAaJv1h

Comment: OK - well if the output has "children" and the str_replace isn't looking for "children" then the str_replace won't work.

Comment: I made sure to change that while implementing the code prior to save. The code does not produce any change in the output.

Comment: I've updated the question and my answer to show the correct class on the `<ul>`

Comment: Thank you, no other suggestions on how to get it to work? Just to be clear, this is the code I am trying: http://pastebin.com/RPLndLpr

Comment: It works for me - see the edited answer.

Comment: I'm not getting the <li>Overview</li> output.

Comment: Then there must be a difference - I just pasted from your two pastebins and it worked.

Comment: On your second step you have the wrong php. The code should only look like http://pastebin.com/RPLndLpr. The HTML is what is out put after the function is echoed. Maybe I need to run it and then go back and adjust it with a str_replace?

Comment: My second step is written to test my code against your data.  If I use the data you supplied then my code makes the change you require.  If you aren't getting that change when the code is applied to your site, then maybe the output of wp_list_pages is different but I can't see that data.